# Returning a value with Redux-Toolkit's createAsyncThunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React application where there is a page that creates clients, from there I send the data to `createAsynkThank` of the Redux-Toolkit, which will handle the request and send it to the server where it will be saved in the DB (if the request is successful, it will be saved in the store).

I want in the event that the save fails for some reason, such as: that such a client already exists, or an invalid email, to send back to React an error and display it on the screen.
Is it possible?

```js
export const newClient = createAsyncThunk('clients/newClient', 
  async ({ name, email, tel }, { getState, dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    if (name && email && tel) {
      $.post(`${URL}/clients/newClient`, { name, email, tel })
      .then( res => {
        dispatch(slice.actions.NewClient({ name, email, tel, _id: res.data.data._id }))
        // return value success
      })
      .catch( err => { 
        // return value err
      })
    } else {
      // return value
    }
  }
)
```

```js
const setNewClient = () => {
  dispatch(newClient({ name, email, tel }))
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can return `rejectWithValue` with the error.

Example:

```js
export const newClient = createAsyncThunk(
  'clients/newClient', 
  async ({ name, email, tel }, { getState, dispatch, rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      if (name && email && tel) {
        const res = await $.post(
          `${URL}/clients/newClient`,
          { name, email, tel }
        );
        dispatch(slice.actions.NewClient({
          name,
          email,
          tel,
          _id: res.data.data._id
        }));
        // return value success;
      } else {
        // return value
      }
    } catch(error) { 
      return rejectWithValue(error); // <-- return rejection w/error here
    }
  }
);
```

The UI should then unwrap the resolved Promise.

```js
const setNewClient = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await dispatch(newClient({ name, email, tel })).unwrap();
    console.log(res);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

or

```js
const setNewClient = () => {
  dispatch(newClient({ name, email, tel })).unwrap()
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

For more details see:

- [Handling Thunk Results](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results)
- [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors)

Comment: I try this, and it returned an undefined value:

Comment: @שמעוןפוקס What part of your `newClient` action should be throwing/rejecting with error, the `$.post` call? Are you still trying to use a Promise chain in the `newClient` action? If so, you need to return the Promise chain. Using `async/await` is easier though.

Comment: I changed the text async await. It still returns me undefined.
The undefined value is always printed as the success of the function.

Comment: The failure of the post is in validation on the server (there is already a user with the same email)

Comment: ok in the end everything works, my mistake was that I forgot to add the word return :)